# SQLServer - Many-to-one update - When updating the 'many', rows updated multiple times?

Tags: updates, sql-server

I have a stock table and a PurchaseOrder table. Stock and PurchaseOrder are many-to-one relation.
An example as below.

```
Stock table  AS ST
POId  |  ItemId  |  Quantity  |  Amount  |  TaxedAmount
A     |  Pen     |  10        |  20      |
A     |  Pen     |  15        |  30      |

PurchaseOrder table  AS PO
POId  |  ItemId  |  Quantity  |  TaxPrice
A     |  Pen     |  25        |  2.1
```

Now I need TaxedAmount = PO.TaxPrice * ST.Quantity
But when I try to do so, every single record in Stock table was updated twice. So the TaxedAmount is always the same.

```
UPDATE Stock
SET
    Stock.TaxedAmount = PurchaseOrder.TaxPrice * Stock.Quantity
FROM
    Stock, PurchaseOrder
WHERE
    Stock.POId = PurchaseOrder.POId
    AND Stock.ItemId = PurchaseOrder.ItemId
```

SQLServer returns

> 2 records affected.
>   2 records affected.

The table is updated as below, where the TaxedAmounts are the same.

```
Stock table  AS ST
POId  |  ItemId  |  Quantity  |  Amount  |  TaxedAmount
A     |  Pen     |  10        |  20      |  31.5
A     |  Pen     |  15        |  30      |  31.5
```

However, the expected results are:

```
Stock table  AS ST
POId  |  ItemId  |  Quantity  |  Amount  |  TaxedAmount
A     |  Pen     |  10        |  20      |  21
A     |  Pen     |  15        |  30      |  31.5
```

Any ideas how I should make the update work properly? Thanks.

Comment: What trouble are you having exactly? After you get the SQL message, do you get those results updated to the `Stock` table when you `Select` from it and check?

Comment: The trouble is, each record in stock was updated twice. So they have the same TaxedAmount = 2.1 * 15 = 3.15. But they should not be the same because of different quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause has been identified. Another update trigger was enabled, which uses another source to update the TaxedAmount, which is incorrect.
I've updated the trigger and the issue has been resolved.